# If both Android and Chrome OS are based on Linux, why is it not possible to install Chrome OS on an Android device?

Tags: custom-roms

I've been searching online for a way to install Chrome OS on an Android tablet and every single answer I've come across so far is "No".

Why is it not a possibility? Both operating systems are based on Linux so (to my very basic knowledge and understanding) it seems like it should be possible.

Comment: The simple answer is it would be possible if Chrome OS would support your device and your device has an unlocked bootloader. But I I am not aware that Chrome OS supports any Android tablet.

Comment: Theoretically you can install any operating system on any device. Just modify it (if possible) and make it compatible with your device.